# percent sign in params to session.get()

Tags: python, get, escaping

In Python, I want to execute `session.get(url,params={...},)`. Among my params is a base64 string. Except that the `+` characters have been converted to `%2B` and the `/` characters to `%2F`. The web server will decode the base64 string into text and run with it before providing a response. Example below, if that is helpful.

I'm finding that the base64 back-translation breaks on the server when it reaches the first percent sign in the base64 string. (In the sample output below, the point where the corruption starts is right where the first `%` sign is in the base64 string.)

Now, I don't think anything is wrong with the server's base64 translation, because I can manually enter the url into a web browser, with its parameters, and all comes back well. (In fact, [here](https://webwork.pcc.edu/webwork2/html2xml?outputformat=simple&problemSource=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%2BWzQwMCw0MDBdCik7CmFkZF9mdW5jdGlvbnMoJGdyLCAieF4zLyRhbnN3ZXJeMyBmb3IgeCBpbiA8LTEsND4gdXNpbmcgY29sb3I6Ymx1ZSBhbmQgd2VpZ2h0OjIiKTsKJHNlY29uZF94ID0gUmVhbCgkYW5zd2VyKjIqKigxLzMpKTsKCiRzb2xnciA9IGluaXRfZ3JhcGgoLTEsLTEsNCw0LApheGVzPT5bMCwwXSwKZ3JpZD0%2BWzUsNV0sCnNpemU9Pls0MDAsNDAwXQopOwphZGRfZnVuY3Rpb25zKCRzb2xnciwgInheMy8kYW5zd2VyXjMgZm9yIHggaW4gPC0xLDQ%2BIHVzaW5nIGNvbG9yOmJsdWUgYW5kIHdlaWdodDoyIik7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbW92ZVRvKDAsMSk7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbGluZVRvKCRhbnN3ZXIsMSwnYmxhY2snLDMpOwokc29sZ3ItPmFycm93VG8oJGFuc3dlciwwLCdibGFjaycsMyk7CgojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMKIyBCb2R5CiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpCRUdJTl9QR01MClRoZSBncmFwaCBiZWxvdyBpcyBhIGdyYXBoIG9mIFtgeT1mKHgpYF0uIFVzZSB0aGUgZ3JhcGggdG8gc29sdmUgdGhlIGVxdWF0aW9uIFtgZih4KT0xYF0uCgo%2BPiBbQCBpbWFnZShpbnNlcnRHcmFwaCgkZ3IpLCB3aWR0aD0%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%2BIFtAIGltYWdlKGluc2VydEdyYXBoKCRzb2xnciksIHdpZHRoPT40MDAsIGhlaWdodD0%2BNDAwLCB0ZXhfc2l6ZT0%2BODAwLCBleHRyYV9odG1sX3RhZ3M9PnFxIWFsdD0iIiEpQF0qIDw8CgoKRU5EX1BHTUxfU09MVVRJT04KCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwojIEVuZCBQcm9ibGVtCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpFTkRET0NVTUVOVCgpOwo=&courseID=anonymous&userID=anonymous&displayMode=tex&problemSeed=123567890&password=anonymous&answersSubmitted=0) is that url. The result may look like garbage to you, but check out the page source if you are comparing to the garbage below.) So I think that it's Python that is not handling the `%` the way I'd like it to.

How can I get Python to handle these `%` characters right? I've tried using `%%` and that doesn't help.

Here is a live MWE, so it has a really long base64 string in it.

```
response = session.get('https://webwork/webwork2/html2xml', params={'outputformat': 'simple', 'problemSource': '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%2BWzQwMCw0MDBdCik7CmFkZF9mdW5jdGlvbnMoJGdyLCAieF4zLyRhbnN3ZXJeMyBmb3IgeCBpbiA8LTEsND4gdXNpbmcgY29sb3I6Ymx1ZSBhbmQgd2VpZ2h0OjIiKTsKJHNlY29uZF94ID0gUmVhbCgkYW5zd2VyKjIqKigxLzMpKTsKCiRzb2xnciA9IGluaXRfZ3JhcGgoLTEsLTEsNCw0LApheGVzPT5bMCwwXSwKZ3JpZD0%2BWzUsNV0sCnNpemU9Pls0MDAsNDAwXQopOwphZGRfZnVuY3Rpb25zKCRzb2xnciwgInheMy8kYW5zd2VyXjMgZm9yIHggaW4gPC0xLDQ%2BIHVzaW5nIGNvbG9yOmJsdWUgYW5kIHdlaWdodDoyIik7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbW92ZVRvKDAsMSk7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbGluZVRvKCRhbnN3ZXIsMSwnYmxhY2snLDMpOwokc29sZ3ItPmFycm93VG8oJGFuc3dlciwwLCdibGFjaycsMyk7CgojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMKIyBCb2R5CiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpCRUdJTl9QR01MClRoZSBncmFwaCBiZWxvdyBpcyBhIGdyYXBoIG9mIFtgeT1mKHgpYF0uIFVzZSB0aGUgZ3JhcGggdG8gc29sdmUgdGhlIGVxdWF0aW9uIFtgZih4KT0xYF0uCgo%2BPiBbQCBpbWFnZShpbnNlcnRHcmFwaCgkZ3IpLCB3aWR0aD0%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%2BIFtAIGltYWdlKGluc2VydEdyYXBoKCRzb2xnciksIHdpZHRoPT40MDAsIGhlaWdodD0%2BNDAwLCB0ZXhfc2l6ZT0%2BODAwLCBleHRyYV9odG1sX3RhZ3M9PnFxIWFsdD0iIiEpQF0qIDw8CgoKRU5EX1BHTUxfU09MVVRJT04KCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwojIEVuZCBQcm9ibGVtCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpFTkRET0NVTUVOVCgpOwo=', 'courseID': 'anonymous', 'userID': 'anonymous', 'displayMode': 'tex', 'problemSeed': '123567890', 'password': 'anonymous', 'answersSubmitted': '0'}, verify=False)
```

And then when I look at `response.text` I see the following. You can ignore all of the html wrapper. The text that was being back-translated breaks down where it counts lines, at line 50, and I've discovered that is precisely where the first `%` sign is in the original base64 string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/webwork2_files/images/favicon.ico"/>

<!-- CSS Loads -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link href="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webwork2_files/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webwork2_files/css/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webwork2_files/themes/math4/math4.css"/>
<link href="/webwork2_files/css/knowlstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- JS Loads -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML-full"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/js/apps/AddOnLoad/addOnLoadEvent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/js/legacy/java_init.js" type="tesxt/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/js/apps/InputColor/color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/js/apps/Base64/Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_HTMLorMML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="textx/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/legacy/vendor/knowl.js"></script>
<script src="/webwork2_files/js/apps/Problem/problem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/themes/math4/math4.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webwork2_files/js/vendor/iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>


<base href="https://webwork.pcc.edu/mod_xmlrpc">
<title>https://webwork.pcc.edu/mod_xmlrpc WeBWorK Editor using host: https://webwork.pcc.edu/mod_xmlrpc, format: simple seed: 123567890</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12 problem">            

            <form action="https://webwork.pcc.edu/webwork2/html2xml" method="post">
<div class="problem-content">

<A NAME="problem13"><pre>        Problem13
1. ERROR caught by Translator while processing problem file:WebworkClient.pm:: define fileName in environment
****************
ERRORS from evaluating PG file: <br/> Unrecognized character \x05; marked by <-- HERE after 5],
size=6<-- HERE near column 562 at line 50 of (eval 1135)
<br/>

****************<br/>
------Input Read
1       #######################################
2       ### Generated from MathBook XML source 
3       ###    on 2015-10-26T15:50:49-07:00    
4       ###                                    
5       ###   http://mathbook.pugetsound.edu   
6       ###                                    
7       #######################################
8       ## DBsubject()
9       ## DBchapter()
10      ## DBsection()
11      ## Level()
12      ## KEYWORDS()
13      ## TitleText1(Integrating WeBWorK into Textbooks)
14      ## EditionText1()
15      ## AuthorText1(Robert Beezer, Alex Jordan)
16      ## Section1(8.)
17      ## Problem1(1)
18      ## Author()
19      ## Institution()
20      ## Language(en-US)
21      
22      DOCUMENT();
23      
24      ############################################################
25      # Load Macros
26      ############################################################
27      loadMacros(
28          "PGstandard.pl",
29          "MathObjects.pl",
30          "PGML.pl",
31          "AnswerFormatHelp.pl",
32          "PGgraphmacros.pl",
33          "PGcourse.pl",
34      );
35      
36      ############################################################
37      # Header
38      ############################################################
39      COMMENT('Authored in MathBook XML');
40      TEXT(beginproblem());
41      
42      ############################################################
43      # PG Setup
44      ############################################################
45      Context('Numeric');
46      $answer = random(1,3,1);
47      $gr = init_graph(-1,-1,4,4,
48      axes=>[0,0],
49      grid=>[5,5],
50      size=6l�������t(��)���}�չ�ѥ��̠��Ȱ���x̼����ݕ�x́��ȁ�����İ����ͥ��������鉱Ք�����ݕ�����Ȉ��(�͕����}��I��������ݕȨȨ��ļ̤��((�ͽ��Ȁ��}�Ʌ����İ�İаа)�����l���t�)�ɥ����R�U���6��S��C�CТ���FE�gV�7F���2�G6��w"�'��2�F�7vW%�2f�"������C`H\�[����܎��H[�ZY����N��܋M�moveTo(0,1);
51      $solgr-6����Q������ݕȰİ��������̤�(�ͽ��ȴ���ɽ�Q������ݕȰ����������̤�((������������������������������������������������������������(��   ���(������������������������������������������������������������)   %9}A50)Q����Ʌ�������܁�́���Ʌ������m�����ुt��U͔�ѡ���Ʌ���Ѽ�ͽ�ٔ�ѡ����Յѥ���m�����Łt�((�����vR���6W'Dw&��Fw"��v�GF��`M


                    ZY�O�


                        ^��^�OO�


                               ^�W����O�\HX[H��JPJ������XH������^�[���\�H�[���\��ܛX][
52          ۝[X�\���PJ����S���S����������������������������������������������������������������][ۂ�������������������������������������������������������������Q�S���S���USӂ�Hܘ�]�X[�Hۛ��][ۈ���
3       OLXH\��V�[���\�XK����� [@ image(insertGraph($solgr), width=>400, height=6�����ѕ�}ͥ�����W�G&��F���Fw3���C�""�Ң�����T�E�t���4��UD��ࠢ222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222220�2V�B&�&�VТ222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222220�T�DD�5T�T�B���

-----<br/></pre>

</div>


           <input type="hidden" name="answersSubmitted" value="1"> 
           <input type="hidden" name="sourceFilePath" value = "">
           <input type="hidden" name="problemSource" value="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%2BWzQwMCw0MDBdCik7CmFkZF9mdW5jdGlvbnMoJGdyLCAieF4zLyRhbnN3ZXJeMyBmb3IgeCBpbiA8LTEsND4gdXNpbmcgY29sb3I6Ymx1ZSBhbmQgd2VpZ2h0OjIiKTsKJHNlY29uZF94ID0gUmVhbCgkYW5zd2VyKjIqKigxLzMpKTsKCiRzb2xnciA9IGluaXRfZ3JhcGgoLTEsLTEsNCw0LApheGVzPT5bMCwwXSwKZ3JpZD0%2BWzUsNV0sCnNpemU9Pls0MDAsNDAwXQopOwphZGRfZnVuY3Rpb25zKCRzb2xnciwgInheMy8kYW5zd2VyXjMgZm9yIHggaW4gPC0xLDQ%2BIHVzaW5nIGNvbG9yOmJsdWUgYW5kIHdlaWdodDoyIik7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbW92ZVRvKDAsMSk7CiRzb2xnci0%2BbGluZVRvKCRhbnN3ZXIsMSwnYmxhY2snLDMpOwokc29sZ3ItPmFycm93VG8oJGFuc3dlciwwLCdibGFjaycsMyk7CgojIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMKIyBCb2R5CiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpCRUdJTl9QR01MClRoZSBncmFwaCBiZWxvdyBpcyBhIGdyYXBoIG9mIFtgeT1mKHgpYF0uIFVzZSB0aGUgZ3JhcGggdG8gc29sdmUgdGhlIGVxdWF0aW9uIFtgZih4KT0xYF0uCgo%2BPiBbQCBpbWFnZShpbnNlcnRHcmFwaCgkZ3IpLCB3aWR0aD0%2BNDAwLCBoZWlnaHQ9PjQwMCwgdGV4X3NpemU9PjgwMCwgZXh0cmFfaHRtbF90YWdzPT5xcSFhbHQ9IiIhKUBdKiA8PAoKPj4gW2B4PWBdIFtfX19fX117JGFuc3dlcn0gW0BBbnN3ZXJGb3JtYXRIZWxwKCdudW1iZXJzJylAXSogPDwKCgpFTkRfUEdNTAoKIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjCiMgU29sdXRpb24KIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjCkJFR0lOX1BHTUxfU09MVVRJT04KVGhlIGdyYXBoIHJldmVhbHMgdGhhdCB0aGUgb25seSBzb2x1dGlvbiB0byBbYGYoeCk9MWBdIGlzIFtgeD1bJGFuc3dlcl1gXS4KCj4%2BIFtAIGltYWdlKGluc2VydEdyYXBoKCRzb2xnciksIHdpZHRoPT40MDAsIGhlaWdodD0%2BNDAwLCB0ZXhfc2l6ZT0%2BODAwLCBleHRyYV9odG1sX3RhZ3M9PnFxIWFsdD0iIiEpQF0qIDw8CgoKRU5EX1BHTUxfU09MVVRJT04KCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwojIEVuZCBQcm9ibGVtCiMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIwpFTkRET0NVTUVOVCgpOwo="> 
           <input type="hidden" name="problemSeed" value="123567890"> 
           <input type="hidden" name="pathToProblemFile" value="">
           <input type="hidden" name=courseName value="anonymous">
           <input type="hidden" name=courseID value="anonymous">
           <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="anonymous">
           <input type="hidden" name="password" value="anonymous">
           <input type="hidden" name="passwd" value="anonymous">
           <input type="hidden" name="displayMode" value="tex">
           <input type="hidden" name="session_key" value="Y8EvKT3YOawEPFVA7XH3MepsK63uAkED">
           <input type="hidden" name="outputformat" value="simple">
           <p>
                      <input type="submit" name="WWcheck" value="Check answer(s)"/> 
              <input type="submit" name="WWgrade" value="Show correct answer(s)"/>
           </p>

           </form>
</div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Complicating the mystery, you can see in the HTML `input` tags that the server has at some level received the base64 string with no trouble. It matches the original one, percent signs and all.

Comment: I've resolved my own immediate issue by rejiggering things to append the base64 param to the url string, leaving it out of the params dictionary. But I'm still interested in any insight to why this happened.